# how to disable home button key?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-manifest

i have done a app..while exiting the app i made password to enter while exiting i using alert dialog method.But when the alert dialog button is appear that movement while press home button the app is coming to home screen.. i want that movement when press home key should disable.

I try this code its work when press home key press it won't go to home screen.But when it open in alert dialog mode while press on home key it going to home screen

```
 @Override
 public void onAttachedToWindow()
 {  
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
        super.onAttachedToWindow();  
 }
```

Comment: You cannot disable the HOME key.

Comment: Even if it were, that would a bad practice to get into.  You would be trapping users in your application until you decide they're done.

Comment: To echo Mike: don't don't DON'T do this.

Answer (score 2):

Home key is special. you cannot disable it, sorry.

You should handle your activity lifecycle accordingly: save and reload relevant variables when needed. Do not rely on your activity always be on top screen!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) { 
        //TODO open dialog
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}//onKeyDown
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the Home key, while the alert dialog is opened, use this code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
...
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

//use this line to disable home key
alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
```

Comment: Even if this works the way you want it to (override, tap to or, in any other way, block the user from using the Home button), this would be a *very bad* practice, and you should never mess with the Home button. *Ever*.